# When is the ubuntu os for mobiles released?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

When are you going to release ubuntu phone version? My phone (Nokia N9)os is linux (meego harmaten), could i install Ubuntu for phones on my mobile?

Answer (score 2):

Nokia N9 uses a Cortex A8. The minimum suggested hardware is a Cortex A9 processor so most likely never.

And if anyone ever manages this (official or unofficial) it will be stripped down to get an acceptable working system, it will still take a long time and you probably already got a new phone.

Comment: There my be a stripped down port version eventually down the line, but it wouldn't really be worth it.

Comment: Yeah you never know but it is going to take some time before it is released and phones get old quickly. Nokia probably has an N15 released before that ;)

Comment: true, or the lumia 5000.